# Using min with cast nvarchar to float with group by throws error in converting

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a select query that does some joins and few where clause which returns 3 numeric values. The type of this column is nvarchar and I am trying to convert it to float which fails and throws exception saying "**Error converting data type nvarchar to float**". I am not able to repro the error with dummy table below but this is what I have so far which works with this dummy data but not in my select statement results:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(Id nvarchar(10), dept nvarchar(10))
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('NA', 'cs')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('1550 ', 'it')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(' 1665', 'it')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('NA', 'cs')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(' 1750 ', 'it')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('1400', 'cs')

SELECT COUNT(Id), MAX(CAST(Id AS FLOAT))  FROM #TEMP
WHERE dept = 'it'
GROUP BY dept
--WHERE Id NOT IN ('NA', '-')
DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Also, when I reverse the order in which I cast and find out the min/max it works just fine.

```
CAST(MIN(Id) AS FLOAT)
```

Is there an issue if we do casting first and then use aggregate functions, or is there an issue with the query in doing it this way with a group by clause?

Note that my table will have 'NA', '-' with white spaces in the result.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: my expected output is to return the min or max value from the query as a float. But more importantly i want to find out the root cause that why it is throwing an exception when i cast first and then do the aggregation

Comment: Please check my answer now.

Comment: The root cause is you have some dodgy data in there somewhere, casting first then maxing after is converting every value. Maxing first and casting after is only casting the max value which clearly works. You can find the dodgy data by using the try_convert function which will return null for the row which doesn't convert.

Comment: i used the try_convert but it only returned numeric values. I think theres some special white space char with those values but when i check the length it gives me 4 for those numeric values :(

Comment: I doubt we can help then without access to the live data as the error is quite clear `Error converting data type nvarchar to float` so there is some string data which doesn't currently convert to a float value - you just have to find it. I dunno how many records you have, but you might be able to find it by a process of eliminating correct values. Good reason to use the correct datatypes when designing a database :)

Comment: sharing an update in few mins, i tried to only cast my column and not do aggregates which is giving the same error. My query does a SELECT and few JOINS and WHERE and then does GROUP BY. Now this column has tons of data like alphanumeric with special chars. The query handles to trim out these other values. I am not sure if that is enough to handle all the scenarios.

Comment: down vote really?

Comment: Probably because no one can help diagnose your problem without seeing a complete MVCE. Nor does it help to post a trivial script that **does not** produce the error. If try_convert does not find the dodgy data, then the problem might be at a higher level in you (more complicated than shown) code. Or maybe you use a view. Impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRY_CONVERT` to make it work always like following.

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), MAX(TRY_CONVERT(float, id))  FROM #TEMP
WHERE dept = 'it'
GROUP BY dept
```

> Also, when I reverse the order in which I cast and find out the
>   min/max it works just fine.

This is working because `MAX` works on varchar/nvarchar column also. And it is returning a number string for your scenario as max which you are able to cast to float. The reverse scenario not working because first cast will take place before MAX, and cast will fail if the column is not a valid number.

Comment: Yes, this works too but please help me find out the root cause why it is failing in my existing scenario.

Comment: so in my scenario, max is also failing. i know my question doesnt provide a repro but that is the closest i can get to explain my issue

Comment: MAX will not fail, it works on string and number both. So it will never fail.

Comment: Yes it will not fail but for some reason its failing in my scenario and for numeric values (i dont know if they have some special chars and trying to find that out). That is why i added spaces to my table but CAST handles it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with case statement as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(Id nvarchar(10), dept nvarchar(10))
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('NA', 'cs')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('1550 ', 'it')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(' 1665', 'it')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('NA', 'cs')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(' 1750 ', 'it')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('1400', 'cs')

SELECT dept, 
MAX(CAST(case Id when 'NA' then 0 else Id end AS FLOAT))  
FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY dept
DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

The output is as shown below

```
dept    (No column name)
------------------------
cs      1400
it      1750
```

You can find the live demo [**here**](https://rextester.com/TRDU52271)

Comment: I have the select statement in a UDF which uses case a lil differently as I have multiple scenarios and it may increase. But trying to find the root cause as why my existing solution is failing.

Comment: The error is in the line `Select CAST(Id AS FLOAT)  FROM #TEMP` because NA can not be converted to the float. You can also pass values to UDF as shown using case statement.

Comment: You should write simple MAX(Id) and not to cast then it will work.\

Comment: Yes, but only if my select will have that value. In my case I see only 3 numeric values i.e. 1550, 1665, 1750 and still it fails with that same error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this
`CAST(cast(replace(Id,'NA','') as int) AS FLOAT)`